# How can I read the numbers from a file, then write them into two files in ascending order, one at a time, into one file, then into the second?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For example:

First file has these numbers:
10 1 5 -3 -9 -12 34 0 2 -52

Second file:
-52 -9 0 2 10

Third file:
-12 -3 1 5 34
My code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 10;
    int *a = new int[n];
    ifstream f("numbers.txt");
    ofstream g("AscNum1.txt");
    ofstream h("AscNum2.txt");
    while (f.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f >> a[i]; //reading numbers from file
        }
        sort(a, a + n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                g << a[i] << ' ';//writing number if its index is even
            }
            else
                h << a[i] << ' '; //writing number if its index is not even
        }

        h.close();
        g.close();
        f.close();
    }
    
}
```

In this code, i sort before "transferring" and  "transfer" by even index(Second file contains numbers with even indexes).

How can I "transfer" without using sort? How can I make this by different way?

Comment: First of all, there's no need for `a` to be a pointer nor for the dynamic allocation. Secondly, there no need for the outer `while` loop either, use a plain `if` instead.

Comment: Besides the points I mentioned above, why do you think you need to do it a different way? Or solve it without sorting? What is the problem you actually have with the program you have?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I think allocating numbers by indexes is pretty primitive

Comment: Can you tell me the differences between e.g. `int n = 10; int* a = new[n];` and `constexpr size_t n = 10; int a[n];` (or even plain `int a[10];`)? Besides that it's easier to have pointer-problems with the first (like memory leaks etc.). If you really want a "dynamic array" use `std::vector` instead (in which case you won't need `n` making the code cleaner), otherwise use `std::array` (in which case you don't need `n` as well).